# can't make a main using c++ templates with definition and declaration separated

Tags: c++, templates

**p.h**

```
#ifndef NODE
#define NODE

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Node {
public:
  Node (T e);
  T& getKey();

private:
  T _key;
};

#endif
```

**p.cc**

```
#include "p.h"    

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T e){
  this->_key = e;
}

template <class T>
T& Node<T>::getKey(){
  return this->_key;
}
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "p.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {
  Node<int> n (100);
  std::cout << n.getKey();
  return 0;
}
```

**g++ --std=c++0x -o main main.cc p.cc**

```
/tmp/ccrIX2he.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `Node<int>::Node(int)'
main.cc:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `Node<int>::getKey()'
```

I can't instantiate any object from main, but if I include p.cc from main it works or simply if I put together all files also works. How can I make it work this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the duplicate question's answer "_It is not necessary to put the implementation in the header file_" However, it has an answer to your question. Just not to be misleaded

Comment: @FirstStep: That statement is 100% correct. Of course, like anything else, it can mislead if you take it out of context and ignore all of the other words in the answer.

Comment: @light I didn't like the title of that question which IS misleading. Templates can be implemented somewhere other than header files and we agree that it is recommended to be somewhere else?

Comment: @FirstStep: I'll repeat here what I said there: _"@AaronMcDaid: The current wording reflects the common view, however inaccurate. It is therefore a reasonable canonical question. We don't typically put answers in questions! Besides, for all but advanced C++ programmers, this_ might as well be true _as goes general advice. So no I don't think we should edit it."_ But feel free to start a discussion on Meta if you want to seriously propose renaming it.

Comment: _"we agree that it is recommended to be somewhere else"_ Who's recommending that? Nobody sensible recommends that.